# What to do with this cash- pay off ONE card, or pay down a few?

Tags: credit-card, loans, interest-rate, debt, interest

I've got a $5k payment coming through with about $12k in CC debt, over 4 cards. 1 card is at $3000 (total line is $4k), 14.8% interest rate, another at $3450(total line is 4.5k), 19.3% interest rate, another at $3500 (total line is $4.5k), interest rate is 17%, and the final card is at $1600 (total line is $2400) and the interest rate is 15%%.

So should I pay the highest card all the way down, and spread the rest out evenly? Or should I just spread it out evenly and pay every card down about 1250?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think the calculation is the higher % minus the lower percentage times the $5k = 4.5% diff = maybe $225 in savings per year paying off the 19.3% card compared to a 14.8% -- after doing that, I'd transfer the remaining $2000 off the 17% to your 15% cards to shave another $40 per year off the interest.

Comment: Where are you getting this $5k, and will you just get back into debt after the $5k? Surplus income is nice, but you also have to think about what got you into debt in the first place and have a plan to keep your expenses less than your income.

Comment: 5k is a lump sum payment - not other debt

Answer (score 11):

Make all minimum payments every month. Then throw every cent you can to the highest rate card.

It's that simple.

Anyone who tells you to pay off lowest balance first is mistaken. Pay off a bunch of 8% $1000 debts before $10,000 %18 debt? Makes no sense.

Edit in response to Kent's comment below -
You sound like a Davidian, a Ramsey fan. I respect your view (and his), but struggle with the cost it can add over one's lifetime. The Ramsey method, known as the debt snowball, comes at a cost. It may be pennies, or many thousands of dollars. It's a direct result of the difference between the rates for the low balance cards versus the high.

In an article titled [Thinking about Dave Ramsey](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/thinking-about-dave-ramsey/) I wrote, offering examples of his method versus the one that appears in conflict, paying the highest rate card first. Keep in mind, any example might appear contrived, to prove the author's point. My own experience was that the highest interest cards offered a high credit line. When rates were starting to fall in the mid-80's, there were cards that offered a relatively low 9-12%, versus the 19.8% that was common. Those cards also came with a low credit line.

To Knuckle-Dragger's comment on the question - the spread here is 4.5%, so the incremental cost of the inferior method isn't as high as my article.

[image]

Above, I line up the debt 2 ways, by balance and by rate. I move the top $5000 for each sort to col 3 and apply the rate. The annual savings by paying each way is totaled. The 12 month difference is $168. Inferior method leaves $6550 accruing interest at an annual $1183, versus my method, $1015.

In the final analysis I'm left saying this - "**Do what works for you. But, understand the numbers, and the math of whatever method you use. Be ready to say that you are willing to pay that incremental cost** because the sense of victory (here, knocking off 2 cards immediately, versus 1) is worth the small extra cost.

Kent - I hope you take the time to read through this, and at least acknowledge I am keeping an open mind on this.

Comment: While I cannot disagree with the math, for many who struggle to pay off debts, the sense of victory that comes with knocking off one of those pesky little ones carries some emotional value and provides momentum to keep going.

Comment: @KentAnderson - updated to respond to you in the post.

Comment: Joe, the open-mindedness is appreciated. The link to your article is excellent, and the comments afterward provide a good synopsis of both views. I had a longer comment, but it was really just a rephrasing of my first, and of your edits, so it's better to leave it off and let your answer speak for itself.

Comment: "Anyone who tells you to pay off the lowest balance first is mistaken."  - That doesn't exactly exude open-mindedness.  :)

Comment: In Dave Ramsey's defense, his advice is geared toward people who are serious about getting out of debt as quickly as possible, not people who are going to take years paying off a little here and there.  Taking the OP's example, if he ends up paying off all $12k in debt over the next 12 months, the difference between the two methods is negligible.

Comment: @BenMiller - I'm thinking it's best not to continue here, happy to move to chat. I will agree with you, as time >> zero, delta interest also >> zero.

Comment: So I'll pay down the top two cards as much as possible- once I do that, should I commit as much money to the highest interest card first, minimum on the others, until that one is at zero, then move to the next one, or once I take this big chunk out with the $5k, can I balance out my payments over the remaining 3 cards?

Comment: You pay the 19.3 in full, then as much to 17% as is left. Each month, minimums to lower 2 and all you can to the 17% till it's paid.

Comment: Two exceptions to the rule about paying down higher interest cards first:  (1) If you are generally good about your budget, it may make sense to have one credit card with zero standing debt to use for convenience and possibly rewards. (For example, I buy all my groceries and online purchases on a credit card with 1% cash back, and pay it off in full every month.) (2) On the reverse side, if you have a card that is inconvenient to pay and regularly incurs late fees, or has an annual fee, you should pay it off and close it out.  In both cases the effective interest rate is not just the APR.

Answer (score 2):

All of these loans are very high interest.  Instead of worrying about which loan to pay first, I recommend coming up with a plan to eliminate all four of the loans as quickly as possible.

You have about $11.5k in debt total.  After you use the $5k you have on hand to pay it down, you'll have $6.5k left.  I have no idea what your monthly income or your expenses are, but if you can scrape together $550 a month to pay down these debts, you would be debt free 12 months from now.

If you can commit to paying down this debt that quickly, then it doesn't matter which one you pay first, because they will all be gone soon, and the difference in savings between the various methods is negligible.

Think about what you could accomplish after you don't have these debts hanging over your head anymore.  It's worth a little sacrifice now to be debt free a year from now.  See if you can make it happen.  The longer you wait to eliminate this debt, the more it costs.

Comment: +1 for thinking about life without having debt hanging around, demanding your money as soon as you earn it.

Comment: Awesome,this gives me some hope! Yes, I have been committing about $500/month to CC payments already, so getting it gown to $6.5k and keeping up with the payments will have me debt free in 12 months! I like the sound of that. Credit Score, look for some new digs! We're moving on up!

Answer (score 2):

Pay off the one with the highest interest rate: the 19.3% interest rate card in this case. Since you'll have $1,500 left, use that to pay off the next one with the highest interest rate: the 17% interest rate card in this case.

Paying higher interest rate debt will always save you the most money.

Let's say you have two loans of $100 each. Loan A has a 30% daily interest rate and loan B has a 10% daily interest rate.

You have $100 to pay off one of the loans:

- If you pay Loan A, tomorrow Loan B will cost you $10 in interest.
- If you pay Loan B, tomorrow loan A will cost you $30 in interest.

So you should pay off loan A to save $20 on interest. Use the same concept with credit cards.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, the answer given by Yasmani Llanes is perfectly correct.

However, some people have psychological problems handling debt. If you fall into that category, I'd recommend paying off the card with the highest interest, and the one with $1,600 (you are 50 dollars short, so add that out of your pocket). That way, you have reduced the number of cards from 4 to 2. You lose a bit of money because there is another card with 2% higher interest, but some people are better off psychologically if the number of debts and the number of bills coming in every month is lower.

One warning: Most of the answers should apply to credit cards anywhere in the world. However, in the UK your interest rate depends often on the payments you make. Minimum payment = high interest rate, a bit higher payment = medium interest rate, high payment = lowest interest rate. So making the lowest payment on all cards except the one with the highest interest rate is in most case a mistake; you'd want to pay enough on every card to avoid the penalties for not paying off enough.